# I'm not getting webhook post request for heroku by using actions-on-google library

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi I'm facing an issue that if i use actions-on-google library i wont get webhook post request for heroku. But  when i use dialogflow-fulfillment ill get webhook post request by using

> webhookclient({request:req,response:resp})

I have to use heroku no options for me. whether it's works only for firebase?.
One more issue i'm unable to get device coarse location when i tested with google mini device but its works fine in simulator.Is their any related to above mentioned issue?

Here is my current code

```
const {dialogflow,Permission,List} = require('actions-on-google');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
server.post('/',function(req,res){
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
server.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000), function () {
    console.log("Server listening");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [an Express server](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs#self-hosted-express-server) with Actions on Google, follow a snippet similar to:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// ... app code here

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json())

expressApp.post('/fulfillment', app)

expressApp.listen(3000)
```